# Weird kill indications in Fortnite BR

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

So ive recently noticed in ***Fortnite Battle Royale*** that I see some rather strange text that appears where it says how Players where eliminated, when... :

> Player X has eliminated Player Y

However, I see some text that makes no sense and dosent explain how **Player X** was eliminated or makes no sense
I see some text I have ***NO IDEA*** what they mean:

> Player X played themselves    **> Explain how?**
>
> Player X checked out too early    ***> No Idea***
>
> Player X 'sploded Player Y    **> What gun?**

Can anyone explain me these weird kill indications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> player X 'sploded player Y

This means that they used an explosive weapon such as a rocket launcher or grenade launcher etc.

> Player X played themselves

This means something along the lines of they took fall damage and died

> player X checked out too early

This either means the same as above or they disconnected.

Comment: Also, from experience, **checked out early** means they left the game early or died early (like hitting water outside the island)

Comment: The bottom two appear to be interchangeable and can also happen if they die to a trap placed by a player who is no longer in the match. I vaguely recall seeing it when I died to a grenade thrown by a player, but they died before their grenade killed me. There is another similar one "Player X is *literally on fire*", which happens when a player dies to their own explosive weapon.